# Golang - detecting duplicate keys in JSON input

Tags: python, json, go

I recently completed a project where I used the "object hook" in Python to detect whether a JSON key was a duplicate of another key. Normal JSON decoders seem to just give the last value encountered, but I would like to be able to detect and return an error. My new project (at new company) is to write this in golang, so wondering if there is a similar method to Python's object hook. I had also used a different object hook to get an "ordered dict" in Python; essentially a list form of the JSON input, with the ordering of the original JSON preserved. Haven't been tasked with that in golang yet, but I bet it's coming.... anyway, input on either of these JSON capabilities as relate to golang appreciated!

Comment: duplicate keys in json is not valid json. isn't it?

Comment: The JSON decoder in Go allows for custom deserialization through the `Unmarshaler` interface.  You can use this interface in favor of the object hook mechanism in Python's `json` library.  http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler

Comment: @fabrizioM correct, but invalid JSON does occasionally show up, from being manually generated or hand-edited. The Python JSON packages I used silently ignored duplicate keys; if you decoded this pseudo-json: a:1, b:2, a:3 it would give you b:2, a:3 as output - the last key value trumped earlier values. I would have preferred it errored on that instead of failing silently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [detect duplicate in JSON String Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107569/detect-duplicate-in-json-string-golang)

Comment: I realize that this one was asked first, but that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107569/detect-duplicate-in-json-string-golang has a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a json library which works like a `bufio.Scanner` or SAX. One is implemented here: [github.com/garyburd/json](http://github.com/garyburd/json). It will generate events as it scans which you can use to discover duplicate keys.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/garyburd/json"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

type Nothing struct{}
type Context struct {
    Kind json.Kind
    Keys map[string]Nothing
}

func Validate(rdr io.Reader) error {
    scanner := json.NewScanner(rdr)
    stack := []Context{}
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if scanner.Kind() == json.Object || scanner.Kind() == json.Array {
            stack = append(stack, Context{
                Kind: scanner.Kind(),
                Keys: map[string]Nothing{},
            })
        } else if scanner.Kind() == json.End {
            if len(stack) == 0 {
                return fmt.Errorf("expected start object or array")
            }
            stack = stack[:len(stack)-1]
        } else if len(stack) > 0 {
            current := stack[len(stack)-1]
            if current.Kind == json.Object {
                key := string(scanner.Name())
                _, exists := current.Keys[key]
                if exists {
                    return fmt.Errorf("found duplicate key: %v", key)
                }
                current.Keys[key] = Nothing{}
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    rdr := strings.NewReader(`
        {
            "x": 10,
            "y": {
                "z": 1,
                "z": 2
            },
            "z": [1,2,3,4,5]
        }
    `)
    err := Validate(rdr)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("valid json!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("invalid json:", err)
    }
}
```

As it walks through the JSON object it builds a stack of hash tables. (for nested objects / arrays) Any duplicate keys in one of those hash tables results in an error. If you need more detail you could easily add a `Name` property to the `Context` and walk the stack backwards to generate a json path. (like `a.b.c.d is a duplicate key`)

Comment: It looks like the github repo for the JSON scanner no longer exists.