# detect duplicate in JSON String Golang

Tags: json, go

I have JSON string like

```
"{\"a\": \"b\", \"a\":true,\"c\":[\"field_3 string 1\",\"field3 string2\"]}"
```

how to detect the duplicate attribute in this json string using Golang

Answer (score 11):

Use the [json.Decoder](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder) to walk through the JSON. When an object is found, walk through keys and values checking for duplicate keys.

```
func check(d *json.Decoder, path []string, dup func(path []string) error) error {
    // Get next token from JSON
    t, err := d.Token()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Is it a delimiter?
    delim, ok := t.(json.Delim)

    // No, nothing more to check.
    if !ok {
        // scaler type, nothing to do
        return nil
    }

    switch delim {
    case '{':
        keys := make(map[string]bool)
        for d.More() {

            // Get field key.

            t, err := d.Token()
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            key := t.(string)

            // Check for duplicates.

            if keys[key] {
                // Duplicate found. Call the application's dup function. The
                // function can record the duplicate or return an error to stop
                // the walk through the document.
                if err := dup(append(path, key)); err != nil {
                    return err
                }
            }
            keys[key] = true

            // Check value.

            if err := check(d, append(path, key), dup); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
        // consume trailing }
        if _, err := d.Token(); err != nil {
            return err
        }

    case '[':
        i := 0
        for d.More() {
            if err := check(d, append(path, strconv.Itoa(i)), dup); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            i++
        }
        // consume trailing ]
        if _, err := d.Token(); err != nil {
            return err
        }

    }
    return nil
}
```

Here's how to call it:

```
func printDup(path []string) error {
    fmt.Printf("Duplicate %s\n", strings.Join(path, "/"))
    return nil
}

...

data := `{"a": "b", "a":true,"c":["field_3 string 1","field3 string2"], "d": {"e": 1, "e": 2}}`
if err := check(json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data)), nil, printDup); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

The output is:

```
Duplicate a
Duplicate d/e
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/BaSRHcnvA3s)

Here's how to generate an error on the first duplicate key:

```
var ErrDuplicate = errors.New("duplicate")

func dupErr(path []string) error {
    return ErrDuplicate
}

...

data := `{"a": "b", "a":true,"c":["field_3 string 1","field3 string2"], "d": {"e": 1, "e": 2}}`
err := check(json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data)), nil, dupErr)
if err == ErrDuplicate {
    fmt.Println("found a duplicate")
} else if err != nil {
    // some other error
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Great solution, however you forgot to return error in case of duplication so err remains nil.

Comment: @eyalP - Good point.  The latest edit addresses that.

Answer (score 1):

One that would probably work well would be to simply decode, reencode, then check the length of the new json against the old json:

https://play.golang.org/p/50P-x1fxCzp

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  jsn := []byte("{\"a\": \"b\", \"a\":true,\"c\":[\"field_3 string 1\",\"field3 string2\"]}")
  var m map[string]interface{}
  err := json.Unmarshal(jsn, &m)
  if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }
        l := len(jsn)
        jsn, err = json.Marshal(m)
  if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }
  if l != len(jsn) {
      panic(fmt.Sprintf("%s: %d (%d)", "duplicate key", l, len(jsn)))
  }
}
```

The right way to do it would be to re-implement the `json.Decode` function, and store a map of keys found, but the above should work (especially if you first stripped any spaces from the json using `jsn = bytes.Replace(jsn, []byte(" "), []byte(""), -1)` to guard against false positives.

Comment: you could probably use ```json.Compact``` to remove the extra whitespace

Comment: I thought the OP asked "how to detect the duplicate attribute", not "how to detect **if there is** the duplicate attribute"